# An insight into the error "initializer element is not constant"

Tags: c

Behold the following code... I am getting the said error for line no. 6...
Pls can anyone explain as to why is this happening?

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct test{
    int data;
};

typedef struct test* Test;

Test obj=(Test) calloc(1,sizeof(struct test));

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Error? This is what it says "Error" and that's it?

Comment: Anyway, functions can be invoked from within other functions. Except `main`. You `calloc` is nowhere.

Comment: Unrelated. hiding pointer types in type aliases is terrible for all but two very specific circumstances (black box "handle" APIs, and callback function pointer types). If this is neither of those (it certainly doesn't look like either, but it may be a stripped reproduction case), just don't. C programmers *love* asterisks. They're the calling card of pointers, and we *want* to see them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `obj` resides at file scope, so it's initializer must be a compile time constant.  You're attempting to call a function instead.  That's not allowed, as that would otherwise mean code would be run (in this case calling a function) outside of a function.

You would need to move the code that assigns a value into the main function.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct test{
    int data;
};

typedef struct test* Test;

Test obj;

int main()
{
    obj = calloc(1,sizeof(struct test));
    return 0;
}
```